# SQL retrieve most recent record of each threadID

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Structure:

`id | sender | receiver | subject | message | threadID | timestamp | date | readStatus`

```sql
SELECT * FROM mail 
WHERE sender = 'redphyre' OR receiver = 'redphyre' 
AND threadID BETWEEN (select min(threadID) FROM mail WHERE sender = 'redphyre' OR receiver = 'redphyre' ORDER BY id DESC) 
AND (select max(threadID) FROM mail WHERE sender = 'redphyre' OR receiver = 'redphyre' ORDER BY id DESC) 
GROUP BY threadID;
```

I'm trying to get this to return the most recent record for user `redphyre` for each individual `threadID` in this case threadID's `0,1,2`. But it isn't working like that. Instead I am getting mixed results between the threadIDs. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: I did, it's an SQL database.

Comment: http://projecttranslation.org/cvlgbt/www/web/mail.pdf is the full table contents.

Comment: @MatthewWalker database type ie. SQL Server, MySQL, Redshift, etc.

Comment: I guess I have no idea on that. My guess would be MySQL. Forgive me, I'm self-taught lol.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, this is what you want:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM mail m
WHERE 'redphyre' IN (m.sender, m.receiver) AND
      m.id = (SELECT MAX(m2.id)
              FROM mail m2
              WHERE 'redphyre' IN (m2.sender, m2.receiver) AND m2.threadID = m.threadID
             );
```

`BETWEEN` and `GROUP BY` really have nothing to do with what you want.  The subquery considers all matching records on the same thread and returns the one with the largest `id`.

Comment: I'm newer to this so I appreciate your help a lot. It's not like I haven't been trying to do this by myself before asking for help, so again thank you.

Comment: Hmm, this is throwing a syntax error. Thanks for bearing with me. I need to learn SQL more intricately it seems. I'm good with a few other languages but SQL was always more basic.

Comment: Try removing the . at the end of "AND m2.threadID = m.threadID."

Comment: Changed `j.receiver` to `m.receiver` (i think he meant that anyway). And removed the period like you said, now it works. Yay!